# How to setup relative path in Homestead vagrant box

Tags: vagrant, homestead

I want to manage my Homestead box on git, so I need to move project file into the box directory structure on OSX. How can I accomplish that?

My current absolute folders mapping:

```
folders:
 - map: ~/work/symfony-projects
   to: /home/vagrant/projects
   type: "nfs"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found out solution. To define root folder of my box I just needed to add dot sign.

So mapping definition now:

```
folders:
 - map: ./projects
   to: /home/vagrant/projects
   type: "nfs"
```